# Ember form values are undefined

Tags: ember.js

I have a similar form, when I want to get submitted values in newItem controller, I get 'undefined' values. What's wrong?

```
<form role="form" {{ action 'add' target="newItem" on="submit"}}>
    <h2>New category</h2>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Category title</label>
      {{input value=title class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Title"}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Category description</label>
      {{textarea value=description class="form-control" placeholder="Description"}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{input type="submit" class="btn" }}
    </div>
  </form>

App.NewItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    add: function(){
      console.log(this.get('title')); // undefined
    }
  });
```

Update:
This form is on the ApplicationRoute:

```
 App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
      var newItem = this.controllerFor('NewItem');
      controller.set('newItem', newItem);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using `Ember.TextField` and `Ember.TextArea`:

```
<form role="form" {{ action 'add' target="newItem" on="submit"}}>
    <h2>New category</h2>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Category title</label>
      {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="title"}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Category description</label>
      {{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding="description"}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{input type="submit" class="btn" }}
    </div>
</form>
```

The `title` and `description` values are now bound to the corresponding input fields.

Update:

I see your target is the `newItem` controller, so my guess is that this form is not bound to the `NewItemController`, thus the values are not bound to the `NewItemController`. A solution:

```
App.MyFormController = Ember.Controller.extend({

    needs: ['newItem']

    add: function(){
        var newItemController = this.get('controllers.newItem');
        newItemController.add(this.get('title'), this.get('description'));
    }
});

App.NewItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    add: function(title, description){
      // add the new item here
    }
});
```

Comment: You are binding those values to the `ApplicationController` (which is kinda bad) if I'm not mistaken